# Why does fgetcsv() apparently sometimes treat "end of file" as an error?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

From the manual at https://www.php.net/fgetcsv :

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.

Am I to interpret this as meaning that "end of file" is considered an **error**?!

I've been using fgetcsv() for a long time and never encountered that it returned FALSE on the last line, but recently, I encountered a CSV file where this happens. Very strange, especially considering the fact that I auto-convert the linebreaks to "standard" Unix ones before my operations with fgetcsv().

Am I not reading/understanding the manual correctly or what?

Comment: If the end of file is reached unexpectedly early,

Answer (score 0):

It just means that when there's an error, or the end of the file is reached, it will return **FALSE**. Whether that last state is considered an "error", or not, doesn't seem relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have misunderstood the interpretation.
`fgetcsv()`  returns "null" if the csv file was not opened by  `fopen()`  before loading with fgetcsv.
FALSE returns for other errors and when the end of the file is reached.
Therefore, a "while" cycle is used to read a file like this:

```
$file = fopen("myFile.csv", "a");

while(($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
 /* now the $row variable is an array where line by line is stored from 
    $file. Here while-loop will read line by line from a file until it 
    reaches FALSE as the end of the file. 
 */
}
```